# Override certain keys in Typescript Record or mapped type

Tags: typescript, types

I need to declare a Record-like type where certain keys have overriden values.

Like this:

```
type Category = "circle" | "square" | "other"; // and 10+ other values

interface DataStore {
   "circle": CircleData; // extends Data
   "square": SquareData; // extends Data
   [key in other Category values]: Data;
}
```

I cannot add/redefine properties in a mapped type:

```
type DataStore = {
    [P in Category]: Data;
    circle: CircleData; // TS7061: A mapped type may not declare properties or methods.
    square: SquareData;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I've came up with is:

```
type SpecialDataStore = {
    circle: CircleData;
    square: SquareData;
}

type DataStore = 
    Record<Exclude<Category, keyof SpecialDataStore>, Data> 
    & SpecialDataStore;
```